# Add comma before uppercase character in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file containing: `StackOverFlow IsTheBest`

I want this result: `Stack,Over,Flow ,Is,The,Best`

(Add comma before every uppercase character)

I searched but didn't see any good results.
I also don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try doing a regex replacement using lookarounds:

```
Find:    (?<=[a-z])\s*(?=[A-Z])
Replace: ,
```

### Demo

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `(?<=[a-z])` assert that what precedes is a lowercase letter
- `\s*` match optional whitespace characters
- `(?=[A-Z])` assert that what follows is an uppercase letter

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, please see the image by following the link below

ibb.co/R4QrFnQ

Comment: I agree, it is working.

Comment: I tried in the demo link it works, but try in notepad++ it doesn't work.
Don't know if I did something wrong.

Comment: But I can use the Demo for my work. It is enough for me, thank you very much.

Comment: @LinhSonNguyen Works fine in Notepad++ 8.4.6. But, you must ensure that "Match case" is selected.

Comment: @LinhSonNguyen If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted. You should also consider voting it up.